# Discord.py (rewrite) mute command always returns the same response

Tags: python, command, discord, discord.py

I'm currently trying to build a discord.py mute command that sends an embed asking if the user is sure that they want to mute, and then when a reaction is added the mute is carried out and the embed is edited. I have run into some errors trying to do so.

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_guild=True)
async def mute(ctx, message, member: discord.Member = None):
  
  guild = ctx.guild
  user = member

  if member == None:
    await ctx.send(f'**{ctx.message.author},** please mention somebody to mute.')
    return 

  if member == ctx.message.author:
    await ctx.send(f'**{ctx.message.author},** you cannot mute yourself, silly.')
    return 
  
  for role in guild.roles:
    if role.name == "Muted":
      if role in user.roles:
                await ctx.send("**{}** is already muted.".format(user))
                return

  embedcheck=discord.Embed(title="Mute", colour=0xFFD166, description=f'Are you sure you want to mute **{user}?**')
  
  embeddone=discord.Embed(title="Muted", colour=0x06D6A0,description=f'The mute has been done. **{user}** cannot talk in any channels anymore.')

  embedfail=discord.Embed(title="Not Muted",colour=0xEF476F,description=f'The mute did not carry out as I did not receive a reaction in time.')

  msg = await ctx.send(embed=embedcheck)
  await message.add_reaction('✅','❌')

  try:
      def check(rctn, user):
        return user.id == ctx.author.id and str(rctn) == '✅'
      reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)
  except asyncio.TimeoutError:
      await msg.edit(embed=embedfail)
  else:
      for role in guild.roles:
        if role.name == "Muted":
            await member.add_roles(role)
            await msg.edit(embed=embeddone)
```

When I run the command I always get the same output, "...please mention somebody to mute," even though I have mentioned somebody. When I don't mention anybody, I get the error

```
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: message is a required argument that is missing.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave out `message` in `async def mute(ctx, message, member: discord.Member = None)` and change `await message.add_reaction(...)` to `await msg.add_reaction(...)`.

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_guild=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
  
  guild = ctx.guild
  user = member

  if member == None:
    await ctx.send(f'**{ctx.message.author},** please mention somebody to mute.')
    return 

  if member == ctx.message.author:
    await ctx.send(f'**{ctx.message.author},** you cannot mute yourself, silly.')
    return 
  
  for role in guild.roles:
    if role.name == "Muted":
      if role in user.roles:
                await ctx.send("**{}** is already muted.".format(user))
                return

  embedcheck=discord.Embed(title="Mute", colour=0xFFD166, description=f'Are you sure you want to mute **{user}?**')
  
  embeddone=discord.Embed(title="Muted", colour=0x06D6A0,description=f'The mute has been done. **{user}** cannot talk in any channels anymore.')

  embedfail=discord.Embed(title="Not Muted",colour=0xEF476F,description=f'The mute did not carry out as I did not receive a reaction in time.')

  msg = await ctx.send(embed=embedcheck)
  await msg.add_reaction('✅')
  await msg.add_reaction('❌')

  try:
      def check(rctn, user):
        return user.id == ctx.author.id and str(rctn) == '✅'
      reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)
  except asyncio.TimeoutError:
      await msg.edit(embed=embedfail)
  else:
      for role in guild.roles:
        if role.name == "Muted":
            await member.add_roles(role)
            await msg.edit(embed=embeddone)
```

You mentioned a user that went to `message` instead of `member`. Not mentioning anyone leaves `message` empty and sends you an error because it is a required argument.

I didn't check if it will mute but this should fix your MissingRequiredArgument error.